# removing items from an array using .splice

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to remove items from an array but it's not working like its supposed to.
Here is my code:

```
for(var i:uint = 0;i<OrderModel.getInstance().orders.length; i++){
    if (OrderModel.getInstance().orders[i].time == hour){
        OrderModel.getInstance().orders.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

it deletes all the items but 1. I always have one item left which should be deleted but it isn't. Any ideas how this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
for(var i:int = OrderModel.getInstance().orders.length - 1;i >= 0; i--){
    if (OrderModel.getInstance().orders[i].time == hour){
        OrderModel.getInstance().orders.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: yea, i tried that one to, the problem is that it check if i>=0, so it passes when i=0 to, so it contracts 1 from that and then i equals to 4294967295 (this is the max value a uint can handle i think?), i also trie >=1 but no luck either

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i:uint = 0;i<OrderModel.getInstance().orders.length; ){
    if (OrderModel.getInstance().orders[i].time == hour){
        OrderModel.getInstance().orders.splice(i, 1);            
    }
    else 
        i++;
}
```

Which is perhaps more simple like this:

```
for(var i:uint = 0;i<OrderModel.getInstance().orders.length; i++){
    if (OrderModel.getInstance().orders[i].time == hour){
        OrderModel.getInstance().orders.splice(i, 1);
        i--;  // if we remove an item, we move the index back
    }
}
```